# How to make cosmetic changes in MicroStrategy Web without the SDK

Tags: java, xml, web, sdk, microstrategy

I am working on a MicroStrategy website and would like to make some changes to the look of the site in order to customize it for my company. However, I do not have access to the SDK or the Customization Editor. All of the documentation that I've found provides solutions for common cosmetic changes using the SDK/Customization Editor. I have some understanding of how the app works, but making cosmetic changes that involve the configuration files and custom tags is difficult without a clear guide.